# Powershell word wrapping at 59 characters

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-ise

Using this command result is divided on two lines, first trimmed on 59 characters, second - all other characters

```
$command ='nuget.exe list "Json.NET" -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/"'
(Invoke-Expression "$command") | out-file C:\test.txt
```

It looks like some strange word wrapping and appears only in Windows PowerShell ISE (Powershell.exe works fine)

Increase the buffer size doesn't work for me

```
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(512,50)
```

this works

```
start-process $nugetExe $command -wait -WindowStyle Hidden -RedirectStandardOutput C:\test.txt -RedirectStandardError C:\error.txt
```

but it works only if exclude "RedirectStandardError", if it exist - wrapping still in place
The same issue if I use

```
$process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true;
```

Comment: What is in the `$command` variable? Is the first line always trimmed to 59 chars (e.g. set `$command = '"0"*200'`)?

Comment: it's get nuget packages list command like: .nuget.exe list "Json.NET" -source "https://nuget.org/api/v2/", and no, 59 characters only if package name is too long

Comment: It looks like nuget is responsible for the wrapping, and it wraps on the window width. You will have to set `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize`. I don't use nuget, so I'm not sure if there is another option.

Comment: I would use set-content over out-file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-Width` parameter on the `Out-File` e.g.:

```
nuget.exe list "Json.NET" -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" | 
    Out-File C:\test.txt -Width 256
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Perhaps it is nugget that is wrapping the text then. Try the same command from cmd.exe and see if it wraps at 59 on the console.

Comment: powershell.exe and cmd.exe works properly if I call nuget.exe from them

Comment: If you execute this `"-" * 64 | Out-File c:\test.txt` is ISE, does it also wrap at 59?

Comment: no,it works properly, it looks like a problem between NuGet.exe and PowerShell ISE output, cause when I call only NuGet.exe and run "get list" - all is ok, but when I call NuGet.exe through powershell then I have wrapping

Comment: @user2586803 It looks like it is related to this issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3673 Since the ISE does not have `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize`, nuget defaults to a width of 60. You could start the powershell console from the ISE with `start powershell -wait -ArgumentList -command, 'nuget.exe list "Json.NET" -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/"| out-file c:\nugettest.txt'`, or just use the console directly.

Answer (score 0):

(I had a similar problem in the far future) `nuget.exe` will wrap at 80 characters in macOS if the output is redirected: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10198

The fix was merged into the [5.9 release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-5.9).

Answer (score 0):

Set-content won't add the extra rendering.  Invoke-expression isn't needed.

```
nuget list Json.NET -source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ | set-content C:\test.txt
```